# Record transformation

Tags: f#

Suppose I have the following type:

```
type Temp<'b,'c> =
   {
      A : string
      B : 'b
      C : 'c
      D : string
   }
```

And I want to create a function that receives Temp<string,string> and outputs Temp<int,int>. I tried two approaches. The most cumbersome (f1) works and the most logical (in my view) does not (f2).

```
let f1 (r : Temp<string,string>) = //works
    {
       A = r.A
       B = r.B |> int
       C = r.C |> int
       D = r.D
    }

//doesn't work
let f2 (r : Temp<string,string>) = {r with B = r.B |> int; C = r.C |> int}
```

Is there another way to construct such a function without having to repeat all the fields in the body?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned before, you can not (ATM) use the `f2` approach but you can simply create a generic version of your `f1` approach and use it.

```ml
type Temp<'b,'c> = {
    A: string
    B: 'b
    C: 'c
    D: string
}

module Temp =
    let bind fB fC temp =
        {
            A = temp.A
            B = fB temp.B
            C = fC temp.C
            D = temp.D
        }

    let bind1 f = bind f f

let sTemp: Temp<string, string> = {
    A = "a"
    B = "b"
    C = "c"
    D = "d"
}

let iTemp: Temp<int, int> = sTemp |> Temp.bind int int   // with two separate functions for each generic field

let iTemp: Temp<int, int> = sTemp |> Temp.bind1 int      // with one function for both fields at once
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. A [copy and update record expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/copy-and-update-record-expressions) can only be used to create a new record of the same type, but `Temp<string, string>` and `Temp<int, int>` are not the same type. I think there are a number of suggestions to broaden this along the lines you suggest in the F# language issue tracker (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1060)), but AFAIK, none have made it into the language yet.